# Adding a trailing slash to a Django root URL

Tags: django, apache, django-urls

I am serving through `Apache` and `wsgi` a `Django` Project. The server url is `http://example.com` and the alias for the project is `myProject`

I'm trying to add automatically a trailing slash to the root url, therefore:

```
http://example.com/myProject
```

should become

```
http://example.com/myProject/
```

In the Apache settings, I have the project alias:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myProject /path/to/wsgi.py
```

In the `myProject`'s main `urls.py` file for Django, I have these entries:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('externalModule.urls')), # I need to add the urls of an external module at this point.
]
```

But doing in this way, if I request `http://example.com/myProject` the trailing slash is not added and it causes errors later on, during the site usage, due to some relative links.

Intrestingly, if I change `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'foo/', include('externalModule.urls')),
]
```

It works: `http://example.com/myProject/foo` becomes `http://example.com/myProject/foo/`.

How can I get the same behavior at the root level?

Comment: is `APPEND_SLASH` to True in settings not working for you ! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash

Comment: It defaults to True, isn’t it?

Comment: Did you try `url(r'^/', include('externalModule.urls'))` ?

Comment: Yes but it did not work